# Laravel how to add a part of url to the current url?

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-5.6

I see that when I have a url like:

```
mysite.com/category/1 - without the closing slash
```

creating a link like:

```
<a href="subcat">subcat</a>
```

will lead to a link like :

```
mysite.com/category/subcat
```

thus it goes back to the last slash in the url, but what I need is this:

```
mysite.com/category/1/subcat
```

is there a way or function in laravel to append a part of url to the current url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the URL helper can help you? I assume you use blade

```
<a href="{{url()->current();}}/subcat">subcat</a>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-url